# How can return an Observable from this method only when a file is completely uploaded into Firebase Storage?

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, firebase-storage

I am having some difficulties trying to upload a file on Firebase Storage from my Angular application.

I have the following situation: in a service class I have something like this:

```
if(file != null) {
    this.uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(file)
        .subscribe(url => {
                              console.log("RETRIEVING URL")
                              console.log(url);
                              console.log("END RETRIEVING URL");
                              ...................................
                              ...................................
                              OTHER OPERATIONS
                              ...................................
                              ...................................
                           });
}
```

As you can see in the previous code snippet I am calling a method called `uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore()` passing a file to it and I am subscribing the returned observable. This method have to upload a file to Firebase Storage and I think that its implementation it is not completely correct.

This is the code of my `uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore()` method:

```
uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(fileToBeUploaded) {
    var n = Date.now();
    const filePath = `user_avatar/${n}`;
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);

    return this.storage.upload(`user_avatar/${n}`, fileToBeUploaded)
             .snapshotChanges()
             .pipe(
                switchMap(refStatus => {
                  console.log("refStatus: ", refStatus);

                  if(refStatus.state == "running")
                    console.log("UPLOAD RUNNING");
                  else {
                    console.log("UPLOAD COMPLETED");
                    console.log("fileRef.getDownloadURL() OUTPUT: ", fileRef.getDownloadURL());
                    //return fileRef.getDownloadURL();
                  }

                  console.log("fileRef.getDownloadURL() OUTPUT: ", fileRef.getDownloadURL());
                  return fileRef.getDownloadURL();
                })
             );
}
```

The problem is the following: this method correctly upload my file into Firebase Storage. It first enter into the

```
if (refStatus.state == "running")
```

indicating that the upload process is still not complete. At this point it `return fileRef.getDownloadURL();` observable but it (at this time) refers to a file not yet fully uploaded (therefore does not yet exist a URL).

So the subscription of my `uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore()` method tries to use this observable to retrieve and print the url (that have to be printed by `console.log(url);`) and I get an error.

Then the upload process continues until when it enter into the `else` statement that print the URL of the uploaded file. But at this point my application is broken because it seems that in the `uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore()` subscription I yet received a value that doesn't contain the URL.

I really have no idea how to solve this issue. My idea is that the `uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore()` method have to emit a value only when the file is completely uploaded and an URL for this file exist.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter) operator.
It will only continue if your condition passed.

```
...
.pipe(
    filter(refStatus => refStatus.state != "running"),
    switchMap(refStatus => {
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you can ignore the 'running' state in your final emission. I would try something like this:

```
uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(fileToBeUploaded) {
  var n = Date.now();
  const filePath = `user_avatar/${n}`;
  const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);

  return this.storage.upload(filePath, fileToBeUploaded)
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      tap(refStatus => {
        if(refStatus.state == "running"){
          console.log("UPLOAD RUNNING");
        }
      }),
      filter(refStatus => refStatus.state != "running"),
      switchMap(_ => fileRef.getDownloadURL())
    );
}
```